# Python XML Element Tree Parsing a big document, returns a subset

Tags: python, xml

I have a big document of xml elements of german text, root iter only returning a subset of the document

root.iter('tu') only finds 82

```
import logging
import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET
class Extractor(object):
    def _get_iter(self, filename: str):
        with open(filename) as objects:
            context = ET.iterparse(objects, events=("start", "end"))

            index, (event, root) = next(enumerate(context))

            return root.iter('tu')

    def get_objects(self, filename: str, limit=-1):
        found = sum(1 for _ in self._get_iter(filename))
        logging.getLogger(__name__).info('found: {}'.format(found))

// found is 82, actual number is millions

alignments = extractor.get_alignments('data/file.tmx', 100000)
```

**update:** Sample tmx file: https://pastebin.com/kUFMMjck

**update:** Resolved it using  event and tagname = tu, I suppose this is a buggy behaviour with root.iter()

Comment: I think you're missing some code here. `_get_iter()` seems to be a method of a class.

Comment: I can share a subset, but don't know how to share files

Comment: please see the latest update on the post, I have a pastbin link with a file, it's TMX which is XML

Comment: If you have solved the problem, post an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

root.iter('tagname') behaves inexpectedly, it doesn't work as expected iterator, and apparently preparses the document.

The solution is

```
class Extractor(object):
    def get_objects(self, filename: str):

        # get an iterable
        context = ET.iterparse(filename, events=("start", "end"))

        # turn it into an iterator
        context = iter(context)

        for event, elem in context:
            if event == "end" and elem.tag == "tu":
               # do something with elem
               elem.clear() # clears memory after doing something with the data
```